# PyQt4 button in Ok didn't going

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

The main window shows the Ok button. When I click OK, it is supposed to appear another window with a message, but when I click OK the window to rotate and it closes

I wanted the window with the message to be appeared and then it came back to the main window.

Can anyone help me? here's the `onclicked` function.

```
def clickOk(self):
    if self.ui.leCategory.text().strip() == '':
        mb = qg.QMessageBox.critical(self,"title",
                               "Category name cannot be empty",
                               qg.QMessageBox.Ok)
        mb.show()
        return
    else:
        self.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the following code will work

```
def onclick(self):
    if self.ui.leCategory.text().strip() == '':
        QMessageBox.critical(self, "hello there?", "Category name cannot be empty")
    else:
        your logic #if not leCategory is empty do some work
```